# Запрос к Paypal NVP Api

Tags: php, paypal

Почему не приходит вообще ничего в ответ,что делаю не так?

```
$paypalUrl = 'https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp';

    $requestParams = array(
        'USER'      => 'jenika.sidorov-facilitator_api1.gmail.com',
        'PWD'       => '7QEM6E28JLKBPE6L',
        'SIGNATURE' => 'A4E0W3p6DNBZUw2ZYCN08fqUfnlGAT4jZ2gf67YS7jmLsnMC-wjbE9I6',
        'VERSION'   => '204',
        'METHOD'    => 'SetExpressCheckout'
    );

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $paypalUrl);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($requestParams));
    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    echo $result;
```

Разобрался добавив в `CURL` следующую опцию

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо добавить

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Для отменa проверки SSL сертификата.
Спасибо сам и подсказал :))

Comment: Не обязательно посылать данные.Если они отсутствую приходит в ответ стаус Failure и сообщение с ошибкой,в моей же ситуации не приходит вообще никакого ответа.

Comment: Ваши  Данный все верны ?

Comment: Да добавил параметр SSL в CURL и заработало

Comment: Да молодец ,ведь правильно на https urli в CURL параметр SSL надо добавлять.Браво :)

Comment: Подожди я щас ответ поправлю :)